# Random permutation iterator

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

Need to augment Enumerable module with new iterator, that returns elements of collection in random order. The only information about collection - it responds to each. No other assumptions about elements.
I have a solution - to wrap elements into Array and then use sample method:

```
def each_permuted
    tmp = []
    self.each do |w|
        tmp << w
    end
    tmp.sample(tmp.length).each do |w|
        yield w
    end
end
```

Don't like it, because here we go through collection twice(even three times counting tmp.sample random permutation). 
Is it possible with single go through?

Comment: If the collection only responds to `each`, then you have to pass through completely at least once in order to do an even random sample (because otherwise you don't even know the length for probability of choosing samples). No way around that AFAIK. If the collection items were addressable in any way, then you can sample based on the addresses. I think your code is close to optimal. You could use `.shuffle` instead of `.sample(tmp.length)` though - I don't know the Ruby internals, but this has a chance of being slightly faster for you.

Comment: What's the problem with `enumerable.to_a.shuffle`?

Comment: @NeilSlater - not quite true.  There's a nice algorithm to pick a random element from a list of unknown length.  You keep the most recent item with probability 1/n, where n is the number of elements so far.  You could augment that to save all unselected items in an array, but that only saves you on the first iteration.  Or just put all items into a randomly inserted array and then you can just pop off an item each time.

Comment: @DavidLjungMadisonStellar So that would still require a pass through the whole array to get you the first sample, the difference being that you would always have a candidate sample in memory immediately after the first `each`, it would not be an equiprobable sample from the whole array until the end.

Comment: Ah true - we're talking about an Array where, once you know the size you can immediately pick one randomly.  The algorithm I mention is only useful where you can't do random access, such as a linked list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that it is possible to do with signle go through. Take a look at this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_.22inside-out.22_algorithm

I implemented the algorithm named "the inside-out algorithm" in the article (it goes through collection twice):

```
def each_permuted
  generator = Random.new
  tmp = []
  self.each do |w|
    r = generator.rand(tmp.size + 1)
    if r == tmp.size
      tmp << w
    else
      tmp << tmp[r]
      tmp[r] = w
    end
  end

  tmp.each do |w|
    yield w
  end
end
```

Tests:

```
1.9.3p327 :064 > [1,2,3,4,5,6].each_permuted { |x| p x }
1
5
2
6
3
4
 => [1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4]
1.9.3p327 :065 > [1,2,3,4,5,6].each_permuted { |x| p x }
4
3
2
5
6
1
 => [4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 1]
1.9.3p327 :066 > [1,2,3,4,5,6].each_permuted { |x| p x }
4
5
2
1
3
6
 => [4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def each_permuted &pr; shuffle.each(&pr) end
```

Comment: No. _The only information about collection - it responds to each_. The author didn't say that it responds to `shuffle` or to any other method.

Comment: I think `def each_permuted &pr; to_a.shuffle.each(&pr) end` would be ok though, since we're augmenting `Enumerable` and that adds `to_a` based on calling `each`.